# How to display value of the already selected database value from the multiple dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, debugging

I have a multiple dropdown as below

```
<select class="select2_multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" id="users'.$id.'" name="users" style="width: 100%;left: 10px;">
    <option id="none" value="">Select Users</option>';
     ... further options generated as per database values (php) ......
</select>
<div id="wrapper" style="top: 105px;"></div>
```

Now I have a javascript to display the user selected values. this will wrap in another div

```
<script type=text/javascript>
        $('select[name="users"]').change(function() {
            $('#wrapper').html('');
            $('option:selected', $(this)).each(function() {
                $('#wrapper').append(
                    $('<ul class="user-list"><li>').html($('<a href="profile.php" data-toggle="tooltip" title="'+$(this).data('usertitle')+'"/><div class="user-info"><span class="avatar"><img src="images/'+$(this).data('useravatar')+'" alt=""> </span><div class="user-info-body"><div class="user-name">'+$(this).data('usertitle')+'</div><span class="country">'+$(this).data('country')+'</span></div></div></a></li></ul>'))
                );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This function is working perfectly fine.

The only problem is it will display the selected values only if the dropdown changes or if the users change the dropdown options.

What I want is, I need to display the existing selected values without making any change in the dropdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**`.trigger()`**](https://api.jquery.com/trigger/):

> A call to `.trigger()` executes the handlers in the same order they would be if the event were triggered naturally by the user

You can first set the value then trigger the *change* event:

```
$('select[name="users"]').val('').trigger('change');
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('select[name="users"]').change(function() {
  $('#wrapper').html('');
  $('option:selected', $(this)).each(function() {
    $('#wrapper').append(
      $('<ul class="user-list"><li>').html($('<a href="profile.php" data-toggle="tooltip" title="title"/><div class="user-info"><span class="avatar"><img src="images/avatar" alt=""> </span><div class="user-info-body"><div class="user-name">title</div><span class="country">country</span></div></div></a></li></ul>'))
    );
  });
});

$('select[name="users"]').val('').trigger('change');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="select2_multiple form-control" multiple="multiple" id="users'.$id.'" name="users" style="width: 100%;left: 10px;">
  <option id="none" value="">Select Users</option>
  <option id="none1" value="1">1111111</option>
  <option id="none2" value="2">2222222</option>
  <option id="none3" value="3">3333333</option>
</select>
<div id="wrapper" style="top: 105px;"></div>
```

**Update:** You can use [**`localStorage()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to trigger the event using the latest selected value.

Inside the change event handler function set the currently selected value using `localStorage.setItem()`

```
$('select[name="users"]').change(function() {
  localStorage.setItem('latestValue', this.value);
  .....
  .....
});
```

Then use that using `localStorage.getItem()`:

```
var last = localStorage.getItem('latestValue');
if(!last) last = ""; // set to empty if null
$('select[name="users"]').val(last).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Thanks. But how do we trigger the selected (previously) options?

Comment: @theveil, in that case you have to use some kind of *storage* like `sessionStorage()` or `localStorage()`. Please check the updated answer, thanks:)